# How to remove unwanted Windows domain accounts and local account from Linux Mint 17 login screen?

Tags: linux-mint, windows, domain

I added Linux mint 17 as a member of Windows 2008R2 domain controller. When I login to my domain account and switch user, I see a bunch of unwanted domain accounts and local machine accounts. I need to know how to remove these unwanted accounts. Here's a list of the accounts I see on the login screen:

- mydomain\administrator
- mydomain\guest # this account is disabled on the domain however it's still showing up
- mydomain\krbtgt # not sure what to do with this one
- hostname\Administrator # need to remove this one, not sure why I have
  two of them
- hostname\Guest # need to remove this one
- Administrator # need this one for local administration

I am not sure if I have to edit and exclude them from /etc/mdm/mdm.conf. I forgot to mention that I am not using simple GDM style. I am using simple UserList GDM.

Comment: How did you join the domain?

Comment: I used likewise-open and executed domainjoincli command. It's working fine with single UserInterface but not with single UserList. I need to modify this list but I don't know how.

Comment: Could you not use this method? http://askubuntu.com/questions/170325/enable-domain-login-on-login-screen

Answer (score 0):

I found this Q&A on AU that sounds like what you're looking for. It's titled: [How to hide users from the GDM login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2471/how-to-hide-users-from-the-gdm-login-screen). There are several answers, but one in particular sounded the most promising.

This one involved editing the schema file, `/etc/gdm/gdm.schema` and changing this section:

(original)

```
 <schema>
  <key>greeter/IncludeAll</key>
  <signature>b</signature>
  <default>true</default>
</schema>
```

(after my edit)

```
<schema>
  <key>greeter/IncludeAll</key>
  <signature>b</signature>
  <default>false</default>
</schema>
```

This has the effect of turning all user-listing off.

Comment: I am using Linux Mint 17 with GDM but I don't have /etc/gdm/. Not sure why?!.

Comment: Are you using Mate or Cinnamon?

Comment: Mint 17 mate. What difference does it make?.